# Error while Inserting into Database an Incremented Index Value of an Array in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

**What I Need**

I 've an array $data[0 to 27] containing different strings. I want to insert $data[] strings in database with 7 at a time, i.e.,

```
$data[0 to 7] //insert in database, loop1

$data[7 to 13] //insert in database, loop2

$data[14 to 20] //insert in database, loop3

$data[21 to 27] //insert in database, loop4
```

**What I Did**

```
    $counttr=3
    $positionCounter=0;
        for($j=0;$j<$counttr;$j++){
            $insert="insert into latest_government_jobs (post_date,exam_date,total_vacancy,qualification,advt_no,last_date,details)
 values ('$data[$positionCounter]','$data[$positionCounter+1]','$data[$positionCounter+2]','$data[$positionCounter+3]','$data[$positionCounter+4]','$data[$positionCounter+5]','$data[$positionCounter+6]')";
            mysqli_query($con,$insert);
            $positionCounter=$positionCounter+7;
        }
```

**What I 'm Getting**

I ' m getting an Error Saying-

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '+', expecting ']' .....

Can anyone help to out and show me How to write it in correct way?

Comment: The error is at which line?

Comment: Look into prepared statements and binding values, this will solve this problem and any SQL injection issues.

Comment: error in the $insert="....." line

Comment: You are wide open for SQL injection. Since you're using mysqli, take advantage of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). **This will take care of the pesky quoting issues that you're having here.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are enclosing variable inside quotes, please refer below code :

```
$counttr=3
$positionCounter=0;
    for($j=0;$j<$counttr;$j++){
        $insert="insert into latest_government_jobs (post_date,exam_date,total_vacancy,qualification,advt_no,last_date,details)
values ('".$data[$positionCounter]."','".$data[$positionCounter+1]."','".$data[$positionCounter+2]."','".$data[$positionCounter+3]."','".$data[$positionCounter+4]."','".$data[$positionCounter+5]."','".$data[$positionCounter+6]."')";
        mysqli_query($con,$insert);
        $positionCounter=$positionCounter+7;
    }

}
```

PS: Your code has sql injection issues. refer this [link](http://culttt.com/2012/09/24/prevent-php-sql-injection-with-pdo-prepared-statements/)

Comment: Thanx Sir, It Solved My Problem :)

Comment: happy to help brother :)